# Swaping on RAYDIUM with python Error

Tags: solana-program, swap

raydium SDK or raydium rust API does not have any documentation, so its very difficult to understand.

```
def make_swap_instruction(self, amount_in: int, token_account_in: PublicKey, token_account_out: PublicKey,
                          accounts: dict) -> TransactionInstruction:
    keys = [
        AccountMeta(pubkey=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["amm_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["open_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["target_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=SERUM_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["bids"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["asks"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["event_queue"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_in, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=token_account_out, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=self.owner.public_key, is_signer=True, is_writable=False)
    ]
    data = SWAP_LAYOUT.build(
        dict(
            instruction=9,
            amount_in=int(amount_in),
            min_amount_out=0
        )
    )
    return TransactionInstruction(keys, AMM_PROGRAM_ID, data)
```

```
  async def buy(self, amount):
        swap_tx = Transaction()
        signers = [self.owner]
        token_account_in = self.quote_token_account
        token_account_out = self.base_token_account
        amount_in = amount * 10 ** self.pool_keys['quote_decimals']
        swap_tx.add(
            self.make_create_associated_account_instruction(amount_in, token_account_in, token_account_out, self.pool_keys),
            self.make_swap_instruction(amount_in, token_account_in, token_account_out, self.pool_keys))
        swap_tx = swap_tx.sign(*signers)
        return await self.conn.send_raw_transaction(swap_tx)
```

I am getting  following error

`solders.SignerError: not enough signers`

There is very little documentation available online and I am new to solana. Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: Please fix formatting and add some more detail wrt to what you want your code to do.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue? If possible, could publish here the code to do the swap on Raydium in Python. I cannot find a working example on the web. Tnx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/7650)

Answer (score 1):

Review the https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/895abf5dfff8d83a1d42aa94ec278e18aad6f2a6/src/tradeV2/trade.ts#L734 and https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/895abf5dfff8d83a1d42aa94ec278e18aad6f2a6/src/common/web3.ts#L374 it may be you're working with dated information as it does appear that LUTs are being used.